# VADER polarity_scores returning output as "Neutral" in most cases

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, vader

In most cases, I am finding that polarity_scores returning output as "Neutral" whereas there should be some % of negative and positive sentiments highlighted e.g. consider the following cases, I found  `{'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}` for all the 3 cases mentioned below.

- case 1: the renewal manager is not qualified at all for the job
- case 2: John was very transparent and extremely diligent in providing    information and setting up meetings for collaboration
- case 3: "Still do not have access to the product ordered.  It has    been more than a week since docs were signed"

Code:

```
    from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
    sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    a = "Our sales representative, Tom, was very attentive to our needs."
    sid.polarity_scores(a)
```

Output:

```
{'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}
```

I expect some % of negative and positive sentiments highlighted taking above examples versus getting 'neu' = 1.0 and 'compound' = 0.0.

Can anyone advise how to get better results matching to the actual sentiment of the given text string? I am willing to explore other libraries or packages if they are better than Vader.

Thanks for advising.

Answer (score 0):

Vader is a Lexicon-based Sentiment analysis library. In the sentence you mentioned the only word that is not neutral is "attentive" but as you can see here: https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment/blob/master/vaderSentiment/vader_lexicon.txt the word attentive is not included in the lexicon which is why it shows that your sentence is neutral.